# where can I find Provisioning Profiles page in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles?

Tags: certificate, ios-provisioning, apple-developer-account

I can't find page of Provisioning Profiles from Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
In googling, they all say " go Provisioning Profiles in Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
but my Page does'nt have that menu.
Do I need to more certification? 
or something wrong with my ID?

this is my Page.
[image]

I think that left side is the place for Provisioning Profiles....
but there is not.

Thank you for reading, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

All the answel I saw are past design of app developer site.
Now that image is recent design.
And we can not get app-id directly.
Make key or identifilers step can connect app-id.
I got helped this page.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-ios-apple-push-notification-apns-get-started